# Python auto-numbering in headings to text [docx files]

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to find a way to convert headings' auto-numbering to text

In MS Word's VBA it is just:

```
Sub Test()
ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
End Sub
```

but how about Python 3.x?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Python-docx has the `styles` attribute. Documentation and examples of use here: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html